# SCP For Secrets Manager Secrets to be Encrypted with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms, aws-organizations

Can any one help me weather there are Guardrails SCP you can put on organization level for Secrets Manager Secrets to Encrypted with KMS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

By default, AWS Secrets Manager encrypts all your secrets with a default KMS Key.
So, I guess that you want to prevent the creation of secrets unless your users specify a particular KMS CMK.

Hereunder is an example of SCP that you could use:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenySecretsCreationWrongKey",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "secretsmanager:KmsKeyId": [CMK_ARN]
             }
          }
       }
   ]
}
```

NOTE: substitute your actual ARN for "[CMK_ARN]"...